# Why does my prop not having my adding field?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

can someone see why do I have `selectionNames:[]` empty when I console log ??

In the rest of my code, I'm using only `selectionNames`, it has the same content of `names`, but with an extra field `selected`. Therefore, I've thought using one sate i.e `names` instead of 2 i.e `selectionNames` and modifying `names` directly in my `useEffect` (to add my `selected` field but it's not working.
Can someone see where is the issue please ?

```
export default function Display() {
    const [names, setNames] = useState([])    
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.post("")
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                setNames(res.data.names)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, []);    
    const init = (e) => {
        return e.map((item) => {
            return {..item,types: item.types.map((t) => ({ ...t, selected: true }))
            };
        });
    };    
    const [selectionNames, setSelectionNames] = useState(init(names));
    console.log(selectionNames)
    ...
    const change = (id,item, value) => {setSelectionStandards((s) => s.map((item) => {...} return item;}));
    };

    return (
        <>     
          {selectionNames.map((item) => (...))}
            
        </>
    );
}
```

Here is my json from my api:

```
{
    "names": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Description": "descr",
            "types": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "decription":"descr1",
                },
                ...
        ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: You never call `setSelectionNames`, and the initial set happens before your axios call resolves so you're mapping an empty array and it never gets updated. You don't seem to understand how hooks work. I suggest working your way through [the official tutorial.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Comment: The component doesn't have props. You're dealing with state here, and state hooks should be at the top of the component. Is `axios.post("")` really your URL?

Comment: @ggorlen, `axios.post("")` is not my really url.

Comment: @JaredSmith, yes I use `setSelectionNames` in my return. The thing is that I'm not using `names` except for my initialization `selectionNames`. I've updated the code! BTW that's why I think I need one state.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const Display = () => {

    // The initial state is empty
    const [names, setNames] = useState([]);

    // This function will be called when component mounts
    const init = async () => {
        const {data} = axios.post('');
        setNames(data.names);
    
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        init();
    } , [])

    // First time, this will print an empty array.
    // After the initialization, you will get the actual names array
    console.log(names);
}
```

Comment: I have to add ` return {..item,types: item.types.map((t) => ({ ...t, selected: true }))` in your `const {data}...` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const Display = () => {

    // The initial state is empty
    const [names, setNames] = useState([]);

    // This function will be called when component mounts
    const init = async () => {
        const { data } = await axios.post(''); // put the await before, call axios
        setNames(data.names);
    
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        init();
    } , [])

    // First time, this will print an empty array.
    // After the initialization, you will get the actual names array
    console.log(names);
}
```

Comment: put the await before, call axios

Comment: But I have to add `return {..item,types: item.types.map((t) => ({ ...t, selected: true }))` in your const {data}? My idea at the beginning was to have `selectionNames` the same as `names` BUT I want to have `selected` field in `selectionNames`.

Comment: const {data} = await axios('')
or
`const resp = await axios('')

const data = resp.data`

are the 2 most used ways to access values.

if you need to change or add something I suggest you put it in a state for later the final result.

Comment: I don't know why do I need to put `.item,types: item.types.map((t) => ({ ...t, selected: true }))` in a state. For me,.it should be in `init() ` function...